# how to deal progressBar from another form

Tags: c#

Why does my attempt at this fail?

I made this public on Form1.Designer.cs

```
public System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar progressBar1;
```

and I can check it shares Form

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
```

and then tried this to update increment on another form "form3"

```
Form1.progressBar1.Increment(10);
```

I made this somewhat weird try because I saw simple "classname.variablename" for using data from another form working...

PS. If I am lucky enough to understand your generous answers... I think I will be able to bite off more of your further suggestions like "how about try inheritance" or "make instance for this"... :)

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: If you ever find yourself modifying the `.Designer.cs` file EVER, then you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: error message is korean text that even I don't understand... language pack for english is not working due to weird microsoft's installing bug...

Comment: `progressBar1` is an [instance variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645751(v=vs.71).aspx), not a static variable. You have to access it from an instance of `Form1`, not the type itself.

Comment: @icemanind: note that you don't need to modify the `.Designer.cs` file directly to make a field public. I agree that making a control field `public` is bad, but it's not because doing so requires editing the .cs file directly (it doesn't), but because exposing these members to callers makes it harder to keep the code contained and maintainable.

Comment: The C# way to do this is to make an EVENT to set the ProgressBar for Form1. Have Form3 fire the event, with Form1 reacting to the event. This works, and will make sure that Form1's GUI thread is invoked to update the progressbar. Otherwise, if some other thread makes the change, the change will not be displayed to the user.

Comment: @StarPilot: I agree regarding the event-based option (and I went ahead and updated my answer to reflect that). However, there's nothing about events that will automatically invoke the operation to the UI thread. If this is needed (there's nothing in this question to suggest it is, but it may well be), then this has to be implemented explicitly. This is true whether using a delegation/proxy design or an event-based one.

Comment: sounds like a pirated copy of VS

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your attempt is that you are trying to access an *instance* member through the class name, rather than an actual instance reference.

When you create the `Form3` instance, you need to pass it the reference to the `Form1` instance, preferably via the constructor. E.g.:

```
partial class Form3 : Form
{
    private readonly Form1 _form1;

    public Form3(Form1 form1)
    {
        _form1 = form1;
    }
}
```

Then you can access the `ProgressBar` instance like this:

```
_form1.progressBar1.Increment(10);
```

Note, however, that making the `progressBar1` field public really isn't the right thing to do. It gives callers more access than they need, when your classes should be designed to give only the *minimum* access required.

It would be better to keep the field private and do something like this:

```
partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public void IncrementProgress(int i)
    {
        progressBar1.Increment(i);
    }
}
```

Then you'd access it like this :

```
_form1.IncrementProgress(10);
```

(still passing the `Form1` instance to the constructor of `Form3`, of course).

**Edit:**

It's worth mentioning that I agree with the general sentiment expressed in the question comments that a better approach is for `Form3` to expose some kind of progress event, and for `Form1` to subscribe to that, rather than requiring `Form3` to specifically know about the `Form1` class at all.

The above code examples address the specific question, but if you are interested in a better design, it would look something like this:

```
partial class Form3 : Form
{
    public event EventHandler IncrementProgress;

    void SomeMethodWhereProgressHappens()
    {
        // ... make some progress

        // Then raise the progress event
        EventHandler handler = IncrementProgress;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        // ... then make some more progress, etc.
    }
}
```

and in your `Form1` class:

```
partial class Form1 : Form
{
    void SomeMethodThatShowsForm3()
    {
        Form3 form3 = new Form3();

        form3.IncrementProgress += (sender, e) => progressBar1.Increment(10);
        form3.Show();
    }
}
```

Note that in this approach, the `Form3` class doesn't have any code at all that depends on the `Form3` class specifically, and `Form1` does not need to expose the `ProgressBar` instance in *any* way, not even via some proxy method.

Finally note that the reason an `event` is appropriate in this scenario is because of the callback nature of the operation. There are other scenarios where some caller, e.g. the code instantiating the class object itself, simply wants to set certain properties that map to control properties. In this case, the delegation/proxy approach I showed as the initial solution is still appropriate. It's a good technique to learn and use when it applies.

Comment: ` private readonly Form1 _form1;

        public Form3(Form1 form1)
        {
            _form1 = form1;
        }` hard to understand this code for the moment :s

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a public property on Form1:

```
public ProgressBar MyProgressBar
{
    get
    {
        return progressBar1;
    }
}
```

Then you can access it from Form3:

```
form1.MyProgressBar.Increment(10);
```

You'll probably need to create a property in Form3 also:

```
public Form MainForm
{
    get; set;
}
```

So when you open Form3, you'll do this:

```
Form3 form3 = new Form3();
form3.Show();
form3.MainForm = this;
```

Comment: Note that exposing class members like this is generally a bad idea, because it gives callers _complete_, unfettered access to the whole `ProgressBar` object. It would be better to expose just the aspects of the `ProgressBar` that you want, such as an `Increment()` method that callers can use, and which simply calls the _private_ `progressBar1.Increment()` method.

Comment: And if it's important for `Form3` to have a reference to the `MainForm` instance, it ought to be passed in the constructor, rather than relying on a settable property to store.